# CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT - while Internet is ok and server is available

Tags: c++, curl

I get this error from Curl, yet, the site is available, and I see nothing going out on wireshark.
What might cause this error ?

I've try to run it against www.google.com and got the same error. 
this very code was working a few hours ago. I have no idea what might cause this.

here is the code:

```
     CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;


    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/xml");

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) {
        struct rcvdstring s;
        init_string(&s);
        string FullAddress = URL+Method;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, FullAddress.c_str());   

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

        res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, DATA.c_str());

        res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        char buf[1024];

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        Respons.assign(s.ptr);

        return res;
}
```

*** Update - took the exe to another computer, it works there. This is local to my computer....

Comment: where is this code running? on the same system as when you checked if the site is still available?

Comment: Yes, of course, a win 8 machine. checked against www.google.com as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Moving the code to another computer - showed me the code is OK. 
The problem was with Norton Internet Security that after a few days of developing decided to block my communication DLL.